# how make nginx process requests sequently by ip or session?

Tags: php, multithreading, nginx

we use nginx and php-fpm as our game server.
we want to make sure requests from one player are processed one by one. 
Then multi-threading bugs are reduced greatly in our game.

we do not know how to config nginx that way.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The web-server itself cannot be run in single-thread mode as far as I know. 
I think there is a solution to this problem. You need a queue to process a player's requests.
There are two options to create a thread-safe queue.

*One* is to write an interface to a thread-safe queue application which resides on the server's memory for PHP. PHP can simply add requests to this thread-safe app and then the app can run them in order.

*OR* You can simply store requests in a database (as they support simultaneous insertion) and then run a program which reads the requests from the db and executes them in order.

However this will add overhead to execution process.